# About switching pages in a ListView

Tags: qt, qt4, qml, qt-quick

I made a ListView that contains 3 rectangles (pages) & they are flicked horizontally, a rectangle is shown at a time & the view switches between them using a button,
I want to know how to prevent the user from switching between them by pressing & dragging pages (he can only go to another rectangle by pressing the button)
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set the "interactive" property to false. it belongs to the "Flickable" class from which "ListView" is derived.